# What is the most efficient and reliable way to operate a critical streaming buffer in C#?

Tags: c#, caching, buffer

I am developing an application in c# which handles a large stream of incoming and outgoing data from a queue like buffer. The buffer needs to be some sort of file in the disk. Data will be written to the buffer very often (i'm talking like once every 10 ms!). Each data written will make 1 record/line in the buffer.

The same program will also read the buffer (line by line) and process the buffered data. After one line/record has been processed, the buffered data must immediately delete the line/record from the buffer file to prevent it from reprocessing the buffered data in the event of a system reboot. This read and delete will also be done at a very fast rate (like every 10ms or so).

So it's as system which writes, reads, and purges what has been read. It gets even harder as this buffer may grow up to 5GB (GIGABYTE) in size if the program decides not to process the buffered data.

**So my question is: What kind of method should I use to handle this buffering mechanism? I had a look at using SQlite and simple text file but they may be ineffecient handling large sizes or maybe not so good handling concurrent inserts, read and delete.

Anyway, really appreciate any advice. Thank you in advance for any answers given!**

Comment: Database (any) would be much safer choice - 100 requests per second does not sound much - please ellaborate or why you are claiming that SQLite is not good and handing sich "heavy" load.

Comment: Remember that 10ms is forever for the CPU; your bottleneck will be disk I/O if anything.

Comment: SQlite may not be good as it locks the entire database during and insert. So I can't read the database at that time. This will slow down system speed

Answer (score 4):

You sound like you're describing Message Queues

There's MSMQ, ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, and a couple others.

Here's a bunch of links on MSMQ:

- http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-microsoft-message-queuing-in-c-for-inter-process-communication/6170794
- http://support.microsoft.com/KB/815811
- http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/06/msmq-your-reliable-asynchronous-message-processing/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973816.aspx
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rajkpt/101262007012217AM/1.aspx

Here's [ZeroMQ (or 0MQ)](http://www.zeromq.org/)

And here's [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Comment: I had a read about MSMQ but it seems rather complicated for a simple application I'm developing. MSMQ requires you to run a service which I don't think any clients would have that service

Comment: Big data, high throughput, near zero response time != simple. What exactly are you making?